# Cannot load such file -- google-search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, google-search

I am trying to require `google-search` gem inside a helper module, but getting the following error on require `cannot load such file -- google-search`. This is working well at the local system, but causing problems at the production server. Though I can find the gem when I run `gem list`. Unable to figure out the problem.

```
module TestHelper
   require 'google-search'

end
```

Error stacktrace

```
from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
```

What can be the issue? How to debug the problem?

After reading http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/require-and-load-in-ruby-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file/ I tried  `$LOAD_PATH` which also doesn't show `google-search`. So I tried to require `google-search` by giving the fullpath

```
 require '/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-search-1.0.3/lib/google-search.rb'
```

which gives this error

```
'/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-search-1.0.3/lib/google-search.rb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- google-search/version
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-search-1.0.3/lib/google-search.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from (irb):27
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:
```

Also `bundle show` doesn't show the gem.

Comment: What happens when you try to `require 'google-search'` in console on production?

Comment: Same error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- google-search`

Comment: i assume this is a problem with bundler or ruby and the way you are running your stuff. is everything run with `bundle exec`? are you using rvm or something?

Comment: I am not using either of these. I tried to run the console using `bundle exec`, even that throws the same error on `require`. What else can be the problem? Any way to debug?

Comment: I came across http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/require-and-load-in-ruby-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file/, and `$LOAD_PATH` doesnt show any related path. But giving the complete path in `require` is also giving the error

Comment: Ah!!! How foolish I am...the Gemfile it's using at the production is different from the Gemfile after deploy..which caused all the trouble and `google-search` gem never existed in that Gemfile..
RESOLVED